# Storing objects for further use

Tags: zend-framework2

Im having some bad issue. Ill go straigh to the details

Im using mappers to hydrate objects with data from database. When i need the data the object1 is going to be created . The object1 contains some data from db and it also contains an object2 which is populated by trigerring event and then it is managed by event manager. The object2 have some data in database as well so im using hydrator there too. In addidtion the object2 contains object1 and it is populated in the same way like object1's object2 parameter.

SO object1 contains object2, and object2 conatins object1.

When it comes to create one of them its going to start endless loop because when i create object1 and it contains object2 the object2 is being created which is containing the object1  so the object1 is being created and so on...

My question is: How to store the object so i wont create 2nd time the same object? SO i can stop that loop and creating the same objects over and over

Comment: first of all you should consider refactoring it, this really sounds like design flaw. probably you have bits of related, but separate functionality in there which can be extracted. In your case you probably can set your object to event object, and then try to use it in listener.

Comment: could you bring some code example of what you thinkin ? cause i dont see it

Comment: Sounds like a dependency injection problem. If you create a couple of factories and use the zf2 service manager, you should be able to deal with the circular dependency problem with no trouble. If you haven't used the service manager and you are using zf2, you really need to get to know it well: https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use events for this. I would refactor to something more sensible for example:

1) You Mapper hydrates ONLY the object it's mapping, it doesn't add any relationsships / child objects.

2) Create a Service layer, your service will use the mappers to generate the objects you need, and to build your object graph as required.

Example:

SchoolService.php

```
public function getSchool($id)
{
     $school = $schoolMapper->fetchSchool($id);
     $students = $studentMapper->fetchStudentsFromSchool($school);
     $school->addStudents($students);

     return $school;
}
```

No cyclic problems anymore.

Only let your datamapper habdle a single object to keep it simple. There may be times you only want the basic object without it's relationships loaded too, as you may not need them and it will be an extra cost to load them every time. Just load them as needed.

You could also think about implementing LazyLoading via Vitrual Proxies. This is a good approach to loading objects more efficiently.

http://phpmaster.com/intro-to-virtual-proxies-1/
http://phpmaster.com/intro-to-virtual-proxies-2/